# Как получить данные из БД mysql при вызове модального окна?

Tags: mysql, laravel, bootstrap

Передо мной стоит задача - быстрый просмотр товара на странице каталога.
Использую laravel и bootstrap

```
<button class="product-preview btn btn-light btn-sm" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#quickViewModal_{{$product->id}}">Быстрый просмотр</button>
```

Как при вызове этого модального окна отправить запрос в базу данных mysql, чтобы получить все данные о товаре?
Можно конечно при загрузке страницы каталога получать сразу все данные, но это не правильный подход. Все данные не нужны и я загружаю только необходимые.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что это нужно в этом направлении смотреть. Но раньше никогда не сталкивался с js. Можно попросить чуть подробнее - что именно мне нужно, чтобы реализовать это, т.к. нет даже представления.